# Another instance of "grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory."

Tags: boot, uefi

I get the error in the subject line whenever I try to update software packages in Ubuntu 18.04. The relevant lines are:

```
Setting up grub-efi-amd64-signed (1.93.8+2.02-2ubuntu8.7) ...
Installing for x86_64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory.
dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 installed grub-efi-amd64-signed package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

There are several solutions suggested on the web, but none of them works for me. I've tried using Boot Repair but it also fails with the same error.

The bootinfo summary from Boot Repair is here:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/p587BkkSHc/

This is on a Dell Inspiron 15 7000 laptop.

Comment: The reason it fails is because it *cannot find EFI directory*. The drive where you installed has a single partition. It should have a small FAT32 partition (100MB-200MB) in the beginning of the drive. It would have been created by the automatic installer "Erase and install...". If partitioning manually the user must create the EFI partition as well.

Comment: The computer has been fine for several months. This problem just started recently. I have not touched any partitions, at least intentionally.

Can you be more specific about what I need to do now?

Comment: Are you able to boot Ubuntu?

Comment: Yes, I can boot Ubuntu

Comment: Try, in terminal, `sudo update-grub`. Does it shows errors as well?

Comment: `sudo update-grub` runs with no errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85513/discussion-between-gauss256-and-gabrielagarcia).

Comment: Have you been able to fix the issue? I have the same these days https://serverfault.com/questions/1065357/ubuntu-18-04-grub-install-error-cannot-find-efi-directory

Comment: As I recall, I ended up wiping out the Ubuntu partitions and starting from scratch. Sorry, that's probably not the solution you wanted to hear.